# How swift compiler identifies variable is copy or strong while bridging from objective-C to swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

*(a)@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *str1;*

*(b)@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *str1;*

How swift compiler identifies the variable is a copy or strong as both the string will be converted to same.

*var str1 = ""* .

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't care if it's "copy" or "strong".
It will call the selector `setStr1(...)` in the objective C class and the objective C implementation will decide if a copy or retain should be done.